# Why is second-level cache used in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, caching, ehcache

I have worked on hibernate.But I am not able to understand when to use second level cache.
I saw hibernate's documentation.But I could not figure out the reason of using second level cache

Comment: matter of performance, instead of hitting the database. See http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/07/02/how-hibernate-second-level-cache-works/

Comment: Yes, it's a key value store, like EHCache etc.. The documentation should evoke it somewhere surely.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, let's talk about process level cache (or 2nd level cache as they call it in Hibernate). To make it work, you should a) configure cache provider b) tell hibernate what entities to cache (right in hbm.xml file if you use this kind of mapping). You tell to the cache provider how many objects it should store and when/why they should be invalidated. So let's say you have a Book and an Author entities, each time you're getting them from the DB, only those that are not in cache will be selected from actually DB. This increases performance significantly. It's useful when:

You write to the database only via Hibernate (because it needs a way to know when to change or invalidate entities in the cache)
You read objects often
You have a single node, and you don't have replication. Otherwise you'll need to replicate the cache itself (use distributed caches like JGroups) which adds more complexity, and it doesn't scale as good as share-nothing apps.
It doesn't work when:

Let's say you're writing such a query: **from Author a fetch join a.books**. Only Authors will be fetched from the cache, books will be obtained from the DB. Joins can't hit cache.
If in your mapping you've mentioned **fetch="join"**, this means that joins will be used everywhere instead of separate select statements. Process level cache works on children objects only if **fetch="select"** is used.
If you don't select by ID. 2nd level cache stores a map of entities' IDs to other properties (it doesn't actually store objects, but the data itself), so if your lookup looks like this: **from Authors where name = :name**, then you don't hit cache.

Now, about Query Cache. You should note that it's not a separate cache, it's an addition to the process level cache. Let's say you have a Country entity. It's static, so you know that each time there will be the same result set when you say from Country. This is a perfect candidate for query cache, it will store a list of IDs in itself and when you next time **select all countries**, it will return this list to the process level cache and the latter, in turn, will return objects for each ID as these objects are stored already in the 2nd level cache. Query cache is invalidated each time anything related to the entity changes. So let's say you configured from Authors to be placed into a Query Cache. It won't be effective as Author changes often. So you should use Query Cache only for more or less static data.

the 2nd level cache is a key-value store. It only works if you get your entities by id

the 2nd level cache is invalidated / updated per entity when an entity is updated/deleted via hibernate. It is not invalidated if the database is updated in a different way.

for queries (e.g. list of customers) use the query cache.

In reality it is useful to have a key-value distributed cache - that's what memcached is, and it powers facebook, twitter and many more. But if you don't have lookups by id, then it won't be very useful.

**How second level cache works**

Lets write all the facts point by point:

Whenever hibernate session try to load an entity, the very first place it look for cached copy of entity in first level cache (associated with particular hibernate session).

If cached copy of entity is present in first level cache, it is returned as result of load method.

If there is no cached entity in first level cache, then second level cache is looked up for cached entity.

If second level cache has cached entity, it is returned as result of load method. But, before returning the entity, it is stored in first level cache also so that next invocation to load method for entity will return the entity from first level cache itself, and there will not be need to go to second level cache again.

If entity is not found in first level cache and second level cache also, then database query is executed and entity is stored in both cache levels, before returning as response of load() method.

Second level cache validate itself for modified entities, if modification has been done through hibernate session APIs.

If some user or process make changes directly in database, the there is no way that second level cache update itself until “timeToLiveSeconds” duration has passed for that cache region. In this case, it is good idea to invalidate whole cache and let hibernate build its cache once again.

You can use below code snippet to invalidate whole hibernate second level cache.

```
/**
 * Evicts all second level cache hibernate entites. This is generally only
 * needed when an external application modifies the databaase.
 */
public void evict2ndLevelCache() {
    try {
        Map<String, ClassMetadata> classesMetadata = sessionFactory.getAllClassMetadata();
        for (String entityName : classesMetadata.keySet()) {
            logger.info("Evicting Entity from 2nd level cache: " + entityName);
            sessionFactory.evictEntity(entityName);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.logp(Level.SEVERE, "SessionController", "evict2ndLevelCache", "Error evicting 2nd level hibernate cache entities: ", e);
    }
}
```

To understand more using examples, I wrote an application for testing in which I configured EhCache as 2nd level cache. Lets see various scenarios:

a) **Entity is fetched very first time**

```
DepartmentEntity department = (DepartmentEntity) session.load(DepartmentEntity.class, new Integer(1));
System.out.println(department.getName());

System.out.println(HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getStatistics().getEntityFetchCount());           //Prints 1
System.out.println(HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getStatistics().getSecondLevelCacheHitCount());   //Prints 0
```

Output: 1 0

**Explanation:** Entity is not present in either 1st or 2nd level cache so, it is fetched from database.

b) **Entity is fetched second time**

```
//Entity is fecthed very first time
DepartmentEntity department = (DepartmentEntity) session.load(DepartmentEntity.class, new Integer(1));
System.out.println(department.getName());

//fetch the department entity again
department = (DepartmentEntity) session.load(DepartmentEntity.class, new Integer(1));
System.out.println(department.getName());

System.out.println(HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getStatistics().getEntityFetchCount());           //Prints 1
System.out.println(HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getStatistics().getSecondLevelCacheHitCount());   //Prints 0
```

Output: 1 0

**Explanation:** Entity is present in first level cache so, it is fetched from there. No need to go to second level cache.

c) **Entity is evicted from first level cache and fetched again**

```
//Entity is fecthed very first time
DepartmentEntity department = (DepartmentEntity) session.load(DepartmentEntity.class, new Integer(1));
System.out.println(department.getName());

//fetch the department entity again
department = (DepartmentEntity) session.load(DepartmentEntity.class, new Integer(1));
System.out.println(department.getName());

//Evict from first level cache
session.evict(department);

department = (DepartmentEntity) session.load(DepartmentEntity.class, new Integer(1));
System.out.println(department.getName());

System.out.println(HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getStatistics().getEntityFetchCount());           //Prints 1
System.out.println(HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getStatistics().getSecondLevelCacheHitCount());   //Prints 1
```

Output: 1 1

**Explanation:** First time entity is fetched from database. Which cause it store in 1st and 2nd level cache. Second load call fetched from first level cache. Then we evicted entity from 1st level cache. So third load() call goes to second level cache and getSecondLevelCacheHitCount() returns 1.

d) **Access second level cache from another session**

```
/Entity is fecthed very first time
DepartmentEntity department = (DepartmentEntity) session.load(DepartmentEntity.class, new Integer(1));
System.out.println(department.getName());

//fetch the department entity again
department = (DepartmentEntity) session.load(DepartmentEntity.class, new Integer(1));
System.out.println(department.getName());

//Evict from first level cache
session.evict(department);

department = (DepartmentEntity) session.load(DepartmentEntity.class, new Integer(1));
System.out.println(department.getName());

department = (DepartmentEntity) anotherSession.load(DepartmentEntity.class, new Integer(1));
System.out.println(department.getName());

System.out.println(HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getStatistics().getEntityFetchCount());           //Prints 1
System.out.println(HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getStatistics().getSecondLevelCacheHitCount());   //Prints 2
```

Output: 1 2

**Explanation:** When another session created from same session factory try to get entity, it is successfully looked up in second level cache and no database call is made.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much whenever we use `cache` in a design, it is for performance. Hibernate's first and second level cache is the same. I assume your question is *since we already have first level cache*, why do we still need a second-level cache?

First level cache is associated with "session" object. Other session objects cannot see it. Once session is closed, cached objects are gone for ever. Second level cache, instead, stay in memory until it is evict for some reason.

Why not just use one level cache and make it available all the time? Invalidating cache is one of the most complex thing in our programming world. Limitting the scope makes it much easier and safer to depend on. Thus we have first level cache by default. Second level cache is more complex and needs more configuration. Thus the feature is there, just be cautious and make sure it is configured properly when you use it.